# Avoid logging specific requests in Wiremock

Tags: scala, wiremock

I'm using Wiremock 2.28.1 in a Scala 2.13 project and I would like to skip logging specific requests/responses in Wiremock because they are just liveness/readiness HTTP calls targeting `health/ready` and `health/alive` endpoints:

```json
{
  "mappings": [
    {
      "request": {
        "method": "GET",
        "url": "/api/v1/health/ready"
      },
      "response": {
        "status": 200,
        "body": "",
        "headers": {
          "Content-Type": "text/plain"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "request": {
        "method": "GET",
        "url": "/api/v1/health/alive"
      },
      "response": {
        "status": 200,
        "body": "",
        "headers": {
          "Content-Type": "text/plain"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The WireMock server configuration is:

```scala
      new WireMockConfiguration()
        .bindAddress(configOptions.host)
        .port(configOptions.port)
        .stubCorsEnabled(configOptions.enableCors)
        .disableRequestJournal() // avoid JVM heap exhaustion for recorded requests
        .usingFilesUnderClasspath(s"$confBasePath/${configOptions.mappingsFolder}")
        .notifier(new ConsoleNotifier(configOptions.verboseNotifier))  // <-- TRUE
        .httpsPort(...)
```

Is there a way to tell WireMock to simply skip logging the `/health/*` API calls?

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways you could do this:

1. Write your own `Notifier` implementation that filters messages based on their content and use this in place of `ConsoleNotifier` in your startup options.
2. Make the healthcheck an admin API function by implementing `AdminApiExtension` and registering it in the startup options (this will mean the URL will have to be under `/__admin/`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Tom. I will try to write my own Notifier implementation to skip all the `/health/*` calls